# NUMBERS- sheet export based on selected data

Tags: numbers

Hey,

I need some help.

I have a large dataset with the following columns (system/subsystem/hazard identification/risk estimation/safety measures). The image below is not in English, but hopefully it will help to understand.

[image]

The result should be a separate sheet of the dataset with the same columns (system / subsystem / hazard identification / risk estimation / safety measures). Based on the selection and labelling of the SYSTEM/SUBSYSTEM columns.

The actual selection of data based on the SYSTEM/SUBSYSTEM identification should be in a similar format to the drop-down library shown in the figure.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: I tried to do it in Excel earlier and it didn't work. In fact, I've only tried a few absolutely pointless attempts and settings in Numbers.